# Size of byte (clarification)

Tags: c++, byte

I'm writing a game server, and this might be an easy question, but I just want some clarification.

Why is it that a byte (char or unsigned char) can hold up to a value of 255 (0xFF, which I believe is 2 bytes)? When I use `sizeof(unsigned char)` the compiler tells me it is 1 byte.
Is it because (in ACSII) it is getting "converted"  to a character?

Sorry for this poor explaination, I'm not really good at describing a question.

Comment: `0xFF` is 2 digits, not 2 bytes. One byte is 0..2^8-1.

Comment: 0xFF is 2 nibbles... 1 byte...

Comment: You're going to want to read the information about data type size and range [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271076/what-is-the-difference-between-an-int-and-a-long-in-c/271132#271132). `char` could be 8 bits or it could be 64 bits; in any case "byte" is defined to be "char", so a byte could be more than 8 bits.

Comment: A byte is not 8 bits. A byte is defined in the standard as the size of a `char`, however many bits that is. ISO (and other standards bodies) tend to use the term octet for an 8-bit value. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535131/potential-problem-with-c-standard-mallocing-chars for more info.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This touches on a bunch of subjects, including the historical meaning of a byte, the C definition of a char, and mathematics.

For starters, a byte has historically been a lot of things, but nowadays we nearly always mean an octet, which is 8 bits. As a play on words, there's also the nybble (or often nibble) which is half a byte (not called bite).

Mathematics tells us that with an ordered combination of 8 `1-or-0` values, we get `28 = 256` combinations. Sometimes we use this unsigned, sometimes signed, but either way we want to have 0 in the range; so the unsigned range is `0..255`. For the signed range, we have [more options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952123/representation-of-negative-numbers-in-c/3952262#3952262), of which [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) is the most popular; in that case, we get one more negative value than positive, for a range of `-128..+127`.

C++ inherits char from C, where it is defined to have a `sizeof` of 1, to be the smallest addressable size (i.e. having distinct address values with &), and a minimal range of `-128..127` or `0..255` depending on if it's signed or not. That boils down to requiring *at least* 8 bits, or one byte; exactly one byte if the machine supports it.

`0xff` is another way of writing 255. `0x` is the C way of marking a [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) constant, so each digit in it is 4 bits (for 16 possible digits), ergo the nibble. This translates to an unsigned octet with all bits set to 1.

If specific size matters to your code, there is a header [stdint.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h) that defines types of minimal and exact sizes, for speed or size optimization.

Incidentally, ASCII is a 7-bit character set. Machines with 7-bit bytes are unusual nowadays, and wider character sets like ISO 8859-1 and UTF-8 are popular.

Comment: I like how you pointed out the distinction that byte has meant a lot of things over time and context, but octet has always meant exactly 8 bits. However, in discussing C and C++ this statement seems to munge those distinctions a little bit: "That boils down to requiring at least 8 bits, or one byte; exactly one byte if the machine supports it." It is true that in C and C++ that sizeof(char) is always 1 and that the limit requirements on char mean CHAR_BIT >= 8. Essentially, in C and C++ a char IS a byte (not necessarily an octet!), but how many bits are in a byte is only partially constrained.

Answer (score 8):

`0xFF` can be stored in 8 bits, which is one byte.

`sizeof(char)` is defined to always return 1, regardless of the actual size in bits of the underlying datatype (see 5.3.3.1 of the current standard). The sizes of all other dataypes are calculated relative to the size of a `char`.

Answer (score 5):

> When I use sizeof(unsigned char) the compiler tells me it is 1 byte.

The size of `char` [whether it is signed or unsigned ] is always 1 as mandated by the C++ Standard.

Comment: And the C standards too.

Answer (score 4):

`char` size is always `1` but number of bits can differ, C define macro `CHAR_BIT` that have number of bits in char.
This mean maximum value that `unsigned char` can have is `pow(2, CHAR_BIT) - 1`.

More info there: [What is CHAR_BIT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200954/what-is-char-bit)

Comment: An often overlooked edge case, important to be aware of.  I lost a pedantic argument with a few people over this one.  Importantly, cppreference refers to "CHAR_BIT" as the number of bits in a *byte*

Answer (score 1):

***Sizeof char or unsigned char is 1 Byte as per the standard.***

***Why different ranges if same size?***

```
1 Byte = 8 bits or 2^8
2^8 = 256
```

Hence,
`signed char` range is from `-128 to 127`
`unsigned char` range is from `0 to 255`

This is because in case of `signed char` one of the bits is used to store the sign, while since `unsigned char` cannot be -ve, that bit is utlized to increase the range.

Comment: 1 byte is not necessarily 8 bits - it's just the most common value

Answer (score 0):

255, 0xFF is one byte when represented as an unsigned char. You cannot represent 255 as a signed char.

Comment: Yes, the range of a signed byte is -128..127

Answer (score 0):

1 byte is 8 bits so in case of

- signed : (1 bit is used for sign so 2^7 = 128) it holds from -128 to 127
- unsigned : (2^8 = 255) it holds from 0 to 255

Comment: 1 octet contains 8 bits. How many bits 1 byte contains is implementation dependant.