# size of types in c/c++

Tags: c++, c, sizeof

I recently asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11600378/331785) regarding the size of `char`. Looking at my question, it brought me to another question:
Are things like number of bits in a `char` or `sizeof(int)` CPU dependent, OS dependent, compiler dependent, or some combination of the above? Who decides the `sizeof(int)` in my compiler is 4?

**EDIT:** Let me explain: For example, my compiler on a 64bit system uses 32bit `int`. Is this set by the compiler or by the OS to be the standard int for all compilers on this (exact) OS/platform combination? How about `char` = 8 bits? Can a OS decide it is going to use 16bit chars? Can a compiler?

Comment: It's platform-dependent what it's dependent on! On any Turing-complete machine, it's theoretically possible to create a compiler that will generate code with any given integer size. Generally, integer will be whatever size the platform best handles natively, unless that's unreasonably large or small, in which case it will be the size closest to the native size that's sufficiently useful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the C++ standard state the size of int, long type to be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/what-does-the-c-standard-state-the-size-of-int-long-type-to-be)

Answer (score 6):

According to all ISO C standards, all sizes are measured in multiples of the size of a `char`. This means, by definition `sizeof(char) == 1`. The size of a `char` in bits is defined by the macro `CHAR_BIT` in `<limits.h>` (or `<climits>`). The minimum size of a `char` is 8 bits.

Additional type restrictions are:

```
sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short int) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long int)
```

`int` must be able to represent -32767 to +32767 - e.g. it must be at least 16 bits wide.

C99 added `long long int`, who's size is larger or equal to `long int`.

The rest is implementation-dependant. This means that the C compiler in question gets to choose how large exactly the numbers are.

---

How do the C compilers choose these sizes?

There are some common conventions most compilers follow. `long` is often chosen to be as large as a machine word. On 64bits machines where `CHAR_BIT == 8` (this is nearly always the case, so I'll assume that for the rest of this answer) this means `sizeof(long) == 8`. On 32 bit machines this means `sizeof(long) == 4`.

`int` is almost always 32 bits wide.

`long long int` is often 64 bits wide.

Comment: There is also restriction that `int` should contain at least 16 bits.

Comment: On Windows, `long` is always 32 bits wide, even on 64-bit machines. Also AFAIK the standard requires `sizeof(long) > sizeof(short)` and that `long long` has at least 64 bits.

Comment: I'm looking through the C99 spec as we speak for further type restrictions.

Comment: `long` can have the same size as `short`

Comment: What makes `CHAR_BIT` at least 8?

Comment: Ack. The C standard says `short` must be at least 16 bits wide and `long` must be at least 32 bits wide, but `short` may indeed be as long as `long`.

Comment: @avakar: It's required in §5.2.4.2.1/1 of the C standard (at least in the newest draft).

Comment: @Philipp: the C99 standard doesn't directly say `short` must be 16 bits wide, however it does say it must be able to hold `INT_MIN` to `INT_MAX` - giving a minimal width of 16 bits.

Comment: @nightcracker `USHRT_MAX` must be at least 65535, and I think that's impossible without making `short` at least 16 bits wide.

Comment: good answer by nightcracker.  To the OP, if you care about size, then use stdint.h with sizes such as uint8_t and uint32_t.  The compiler vendors supply a standard implementation for a given target.  The compiler will decide how to use this based on the native word size of the target CPU.

Comment: @Philipp: Re your last comment. It does not imply that it must be exactly 16bits either. An implementation could decide that all integral types are 64bits and you would have `sizeof(short)==sizeof(long)`. There are different constraints, one on the ordering of the sizes (`<=`) and on the minimal sizes of different types) but `sizeof(short) < sizeof(long)` is not a result of the combination of constraints.

Answer (score 3):

> Are things like number of bits in a char or sizeof(int) CPU dependent, OS dependent, compiler dependent, or some combination of the above?

Compiler-dependent. And your compiler is CPU-dependent and OS-dependent by itself.

This means that if you compile a program on your PC where `int` or `void*` have 4 bytes, and move the executable to a different machine, it can't happen that it would be a different number of bytes there. The compiler outputs machine code for a specific machine.

But if you compile the same source on a different compiler, or the same compiler version but for a different OS, or on the same compiler but with different settings, then you may encounter changes.

For instance, on my PC with a 64-bit GCC, `void*` takes 8 bytes, but it I compile with `-m32` it would take 4 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's compiler which sets those informations. And he do this according to software/hardware details (such as CPU or OS as you said).