# what actually decide how many bits an integer is

Tags: android, assembly, embedded

I'm writing an app for my android device. And I'm performing some native developing. And I'm using android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-9. 
So now in my C codes, I'm declaring`int j=2;`
But how many bytes is `j`, and it is determined by what? the linux kernel of my android device or the arm chip? I understand that the corresponding assembling code for that is

```
.data
j: .word 2
```

but that does not gives how much space this `j` will occupy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [size of types in c/c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600536/size-of-types-in-c-c)

Comment: It is determined by the language, C or assembly, etc.  specifically that compiler/assembler (and chosen by the tool authors).  Often it matches the general purpose register size, but not always.  And doesnt have to match from one compiler to another or one compiler to an assembler nor one version of anything to anything.  completely up to the tool author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The architecture and toolchain define the sizes of types, so yes, it's partly ARM and partly the compiler you're using to build for it.  Normally on ARM that means a 32-bit `int` type.
2. The `.word` assembly keyword will be described in the assembler documentation, where it will let you know how large the type is.  Normally `.word` is a 32-bit type for ARM.

Comment: No, it is entirely the compiler, and not the architecture at all.  Of course, commonly the compiler configuration is inspired by the architecture as a matter of convenience and efficiency, but it can in fact completely ignore this in the programming model it presents, as long as the back end targets the actual hardware.  The size of something like a pointer however, would need to match that of the addressing mode in use, if the programmer view of memory is going to match the execution mode.

Comment: Yes, that's true.  In practice, as you say, the architecture tends to lend itself to particular implementation choices.

Comment: @ChrisStratton While in theory, nothing has to be the same.  Take *java* compiling to byte code.  However, most compilers strive to be efficient.  Ergo, they will want to match the underlying hardware.  So, I think *theory* and *practice* maybe different. 2nd, compilers often strive to be *ABI* compliant and this is mandated by the architecture via efficiency.

Comment: You don't have to run on a vm for a compiler to implement data types of a different width from the ALU.  An ABI is a contract between programmers, not a contract with the hardware.  I've worked on a platform using a compiler and ABI which specified a 32-bit int despite the most hardware efficient operation size being 16 bits - this was done to allow it to conveniently run Linux.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I mentioned a **VM** only to point out that pointers don't have to match the underlying arch either.  The majority of compilers will match the underlying arch.  The 'C' standard is written to allow this and given no other criteria, they will.  Of course, you can make a system that does not follow the arch.  Your first comment seems to imply that it is completely capricious as to what the compiler picks; Ie. *not the architecture at all*.