# why it shows like this in hexadecimal notation?

Tags: c

I'm trying to do bit arithmetic with variables `a` and `b`. When I reverse `a`, which has the value 0xAF, the result shows as 8 digits.
Unlike the others that show as 2 digits.

I don't know why it happens, but guess that it is relevant to `%x`'s showing way and little endian?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a = 0xAF; // 10101111
    int b = 0xB5; // 10110101

    printf("%x \n", a & b); // a & b = 10100101
    printf("%x \n", a | b); // a | b = 10111111
    printf("%x \n", a ^ b); // a ^ b = 00011010
    printf("%x \n", ~a); // ~a = 1....1 01010000
    printf("%x \n", a << 2);// a << 2 = 1010111100 
    printf("%x \n", b >> 3); // b >> 3 = 00010110 

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a lot of potential problems with code like this.

Most importantly, you should never use signed integer types like `int` when doing bitwise operations. Because you could either end up with unexpected results, or you could end up with undefined/implementation-defined behavior bugs if using operators like `<<` `>>` on negative value integers.

So step one is to ensure you have an unsigned integer type. Preferably `uint32_t` or similar from `stdint.h`.

Another related problem is that if you use small integer types in an expression, such as `uint8_t`, `char`, `short`, `bool` etc, then they will get implicitly promoted to type `int`, which is a signed type. You get that even if you use `unsigned char` or `uint8_t`. This is the source of many fatal bugs related to the bitwise operators.

And finally, the `printf` family of functions is dangerous to use when you need to be explicit about types. While these function have literally zero type safety, they at the same time assume a certain, specific type. If you give them the wrong type you invoke undefined behavior and the program will potentially crash & burn. Also, being variable-argument list functions, they also use implicit promotion of the arguments (default argument promotions) which might also cause unforeseen bugs.

---

The "strange" output you experience is a combination of doing bitwise `~` on a signed type and `printf` expecting an `unsigned int` when you give it the `%x` conversion specifier.

In order to get more deterministic output, you could do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main()
{
    uint32_t a = 0xAF; // 10101111
    uint32_t b = 0xB5; // 10110101

    printf("%.8" PRIx32 "\n", a & b);  // a & b = 10100101
    printf("%.8" PRIx32 "\n", a | b);  // a | b = 10111111
    printf("%.8" PRIx32 "\n", a ^ b);  // a ^ b = 00011010
    printf("%.8" PRIx32 "\n", ~a);     // ~a = 1....1 01010000
    printf("%.8" PRIx32 "\n", a << 2); // a << 2 = 1010111100 
    printf("%.8" PRIx32 "\n", b >> 3); // b >> 3 = 00010110 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For example, `char a = 0xAF; ... a << 2` invokes undefined behavior if `char` is signed.

Comment: Your answer was really helpful for me. But i'm a student learning C Language. So there are expssions that i can't understand on your answer. How could i get the information about PRix32 and %.8 and uint32_t?

Comment: @Ongbune `%.8` is a standard printf specifier stating how many digits you want it to print out, regardless of how large the number is. `uint32_t` is one of many fixed-width integers that were introduced to the language with the C99 standard, they are found in the `stdint.h` header, so I would imagine that searching for information about `stdint.h` would give more info. `PRIx32` is a format specifier which can use to `printf` these types - all those format specifiers for the stdint types are found in `inttypes.h`.

Comment: Since I knew that `inttypes.h` must include `stdint.h` internally, I sloppily skipped the `#include <stdint.h>`.

Comment: And yes, the bitwise operators only allow integer types.

Comment: Very good explanation.  You might add that compiler warnings can help track argument type mismatches for the `printf` and `scanf` families of functions (`gcc -Wall -Wextra` and `clang -Wall -Weverything`

Answer (score 6):

Considering your `int a` is most likely 32 bit in size, your `a` actually looks like this:

```
int a = 0xAF; // 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1010 1111
```

So if you flip all the bits on that, you have

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0101 0000
```

Or, in hex

```
0xFFFFFF50
```

Which is exactly what you're getting. The others show only 2 digits because trailing zeroes are omitted when printing hex, and your other bit operations do not in fact change any of the leading zeroes.

---- Credit to @ chqrlie for this ----
If you really only want to see 8 bits of the result, you can do

```
printf("%hhx \n", ~a); // ~a = 1....1 01010000 --> Output : 50
```

Which restricts the printed value to `unsigned char` (8 bit [on modern os, not guaranteed, but very likely for your purposes]) length.

Comment: @dhke Yes, I just noticed and fixed it a few seconds ago :)

Comment: `uint8_t a = 0xAF; ... ~a` would give the very same result so that advise is not good. Proper, bug free code is `printf("%" PRIX32 "\n", ~(uint32_t)a);`

Comment: Using a type `uint8_t` will not change anything as the expression is evaluated as `int` anyway.  You can use format `%hhx` to print the value restricted to `unsigned char`, most likely 8 bits.

Comment: @Lundin I already added a caveat with credit to your comment in the last part of the answer.

Comment: @chqrlie Thanks for the suggestion, I will add that with credit to the answer.

Comment: Also `unsigned char` is **not** guaranteed to be 8 bits, if it is not, type `uint8_t` is probably not present either.

Comment: @chqrlie Are you sure of that? I was always under the impression that sizeof(char) and sizeof(unsigned char) is mandated to be 1 (1 byte == 8 bits)?

Comment: 1 byte is not necessarily 8 bits - the no of bits in a `char` is defined in `CHAR_BIT` - better to use `uint8_t`, although you're unlikely to run into problems unless you work on DSPs or other esoteric systems.

Comment: @PaulR Wait what? How could 1 byte possibly not be 8 bits? Do you have an example for this?

Comment: This has been covered many times on StackOverflow (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600378/portable-code-bits-per-char) - most modern conventional platforms have 1 byte = 8 bits, but it's not universal. In C a `char` is always one byte and is required to have *at least* 8 bits. I know of systems where `CHAR_BIT` can be 9 bits or even 24 bits - and there are probably others.

Comment: @Magisch: `sizeof(char)` and `sizeof(unsigned char)` are indeed equal to `1` by definition and type `unsigned char` is mandated to be at least 8 bits, but some architectures do not support 8 bit bytes: bytes there can be 9 bits (some older mainframes) or even 16 or 32 bits (some DSP and embedded calculators), or any size greater than 8.

Comment: See [this section of the Wikipedia entry for "byte"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte#Common_uses) and also note the use of the more accurate term "octet" for an 8 bit byte.